# Inaccessible SD Card Reader - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, sd-card, card-reader

I've got a dell xps 9500 dual booted with windows 10/ubuntu 20.04 that recently started having problems with the SD card reader. A few days ago, I was able to put in my SD card and it would mount without issue, however now nothing happens at all when I put in the exact same SD card. I tried a few solutions including:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks2
```

and

```
sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

however both of these didn't help.

Finally, the piece of the command lspci -v which shows the card reader is:

```
6d:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at b4100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

I think it might be important to also note that if I use an external USB to SD adapter, the SD card mounts without issue, and the SD card and card reader work just fine on the windows partition. Has anyone had issues where their SD card readers similar to this?

Comment: I think I am experiencing the same issue with a Precision 7550. I wasn't certain that my SD-card reader worked a few weeks ago, but it certainly isn't working now.

Comment: I installed kernel 5.8.0-33-generic #36~20.04.1-Ubuntu and now the SD-card reader work (sort of). When I plug in a SD-card it is recognised only once I also run a lspci command; same goes for removal. I cannot say if the data written is correctly or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling secure boot in the Windows 10 BIOS solved this issue for me.